# Merge multiple custom post types in a single archive template

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I have multiple custom post types, viz., *research*, *documents*, *booklets*.
I have a single archive template for each of them , *archive-research.php*, *archive-documents.php*, *archive-booklets.php* respectively.

I need another template where I display posts from all these CPTs.

For a single CPT, I used the following code:

```
query_posts( 
  array(
    'post_type' => 'post_type_name_here',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged'=>$paged
  ) 
);
```

Is there any way to merge theme?

Comment: What do you mean merge?

Comment: None of your existing templates should be using `query_posts()`. WordPress will query the correct posts for you.

Comment: Create a new page template and use `WP_Query` with the `post_type` key having an array with all your post types.

Comment: @Karun that's the answer I needed. I don't know that we can use an array for `post_type`. Thanks

Comment: @SundayLalbiaknia use this `'post_type' => array('viz', 'research', 'documents', 'booklets'),`

Comment: @Karun, I used that. Its working for me.

Comment: @SundayLalbiaknia Good to know. You can probably set this as resolved.

Answer (score 4):

As Jacob Peattle mentioned, you should not be using query_posts in your custom archive templates, that's redundant as WP is already going to query those posts for you. What you really need is `pre_get_posts` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). That will allow you to conditionally modify the parameters of the main query before it executes. Additionally since you are effectively executing the same query for all 4 CPTs, then it's unnecessary to have 4 separate templates to do so, instead take a look at the `template_include` filter https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

Add the following to your functions file...

```
//Modify the main query    
function custom_archive_query($query){
   if(is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()){
      return;
   }
   $cpts = array("research","documents","booklets");
   if(is_post_type_archive($cpts)){
      $query->set('post_type', $cpts);
      return;
   }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_archive_query');

//Add the template redirect
function custom_archive_template($template){
   $cpts = array("research","documents","booklets");
   if(is_post_type_archive($cpts)){
      $new_template = locate_template( array( 'custom_archive-template.php' ) );
      if(!empty($new_template)) return $new_template;
   }
   return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'custom_archive_template');
```

As an additional note, you may need to adjust your query more than this example, and obviously your custom post type names to match. Your original query is paging at 4 posts per page, that may have undesired results due to the fact that you're combining multiple post types.

Comment: I had the same issue, this solved my problem. Thanks.